# Django / MySql and 4 Byte UTF-8 characters

Tags: django

I want to store 4-byte utf-8 characters in my django models with a mysql backend.

I read that MySql does not support 4 byte utf-8 characters but changing the encoding to utf8mb4 would solve this issue. I changed the encoding and verified the settings:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%';

character_set_client - utf8mb4
character_set_connection - utf8mb4
character_set_database - utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_results - utf8mb4
character_set_server - latin1
character_set_system - utf8
```

When I try to send the "pile of poo" (as an example) I still get `OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\xA9' for column 'text' at row 1")`

I also tried to insert the pile of poo manually to an entry in my database. That worked and the database accepted the emoji. On my django view there is only "??" showing up.

Comment: What is the character set of the `text` column of the table you're trying to insert into?

Comment: I set it to utf8mb4

Comment: Make sure your client is connecting as utf8mb4, and that your tables are all in utf8mb4 with all the columns converted. It's definitely possible with Django as I do it, for example in the tests for django-mysql: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/blob/master/tests/settings.py P.S. please remove the tag django-mysql from this question as it's for my library django-mysql

Comment: I added the additional OPTION to Django as mentioned in the repository. That solved the issue. Thanks!